# Get working of Random Forest in GEE in understandable form

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification, random-forest

I used this code to see decion tree in RF GEE:

```
var decisionTrees = ee.List(trained.explain().get('trees'))
print("Tree decision", decisionTrees)
```

I get this:

```
Tree decision
List (29 elements)
0: n= 116838
node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
* denotes terminal node
1) root 116838 31180 8 (0.010997 0.0066155 0.019316 0.013984 0.012195 0.016243 0.055491 0.011528 0.85363)
 2) B3_winter<=0.353869 17121 13722 6 (0.073555 0.044600 0.12796 0.091710 0.082896 0.11033 0.37828 0.047577 0.043082)  ........
```

How can I get it in a more understandable form for interpretation as tree
look like this [image]

Comment: I doubt tree visualization is currently unavailable in GEE.